# How can I delete a pointer from an array of pointers in parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my Android app I have a subclass of ParseObject called AppUser, in it there is a field called "favorites", which is an array of another subclass of ParseObject called DateMeeting.
when I delete a DateMeeting object, the pointer to it in "favorites" remains. how can I delete this pointer ?
It would be best if I could it in java, with no cloud code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List of WeakReference to DateMeeting instead of List of DateMeeting

```
class AppUser extends ParseObject { 
    List<WeakReference<DateMeeting>> favorites;
} 

class DateMeeting extends ParseObject{}
```

In this way, when you want to delete an instance of DateMeeting the reference in favorites list will not maintain it still in life.

The list of favorites does not reduce its size when you release a DateMeeting object, but you can check if object is still present with check (suppose i is an index to move into the list)

```
if (favorites.get(i).get()!=null)
{
  // object at i-position is still live
}
```

For more information check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked this way. Assuming that you have your `AppUser` and your `DateMeeting` already.

```
AppUser appUser = ...
DateMeeting dateMeeting = ...

...

// remove pointer from appUser
DateMeeting[] meetings = new DateMeeting[] {dateMeeting};
appUser.removeAll("favorites", Arrays.asList(meetings));
appUser.saveInBackground();

// now you can delete the meeting
dateMeeting.deleteInBackground();
```